# the number of rows does not show up

Tags: php, mysqli

I do not understand that what's wrong with this file. I try to show in the website the number of rows, but it seems like mysqli_num_rows function doesn't work.

```
<?php

$con4 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con4))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


        $sqlquery4 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' AND oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'";
        $query = mysqli_query($con4, $sqlquery4);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        if( !empty($result) ) { /* user exist */  } else {

if( strlen($shkurtimi) > 0) { 
$vlera = $shkurtimi;
} else {
$vlera = $username;
}

$sqlusernameinjejte = "SELECT username, id, verifikuar FROM users WHERE username = '$vlera' AND verifikuar = 'po'";
$queryusernamenjejt = mysqli_query($con4, $sqlusernameinjejte);
$numusernamenjejt = mysqli_num_rows($queryusernamenjejt);
echo "1) number of rows --> " . $numusernamenjejt;

$sqlemailinjejte = "SELECT email, id, verifikuar FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND verifikuar = 'po'";
$queryemailnjejt = mysqli_query($con4, $sqlemailinjejte);
$numemailnjejt = mysqli_num_rows($queryemailnjejt);
echo "2) number of rows --> " . $numemailnjejt;



        }

?>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What about error reporting?

Comment: So what actually is output? Do you have any errors? is `empty($result) == true`?

Comment: mysqli_numrows now presents some changes and with that people are having errors I suggest to look in deeper the php manual about mysqli_numrows.

Comment: The output is: 

1) number of rows --> 2) number of rows -->